# fixed paths for jquery ajax calls

Tags: jquery

I want an absolute path in ajax, but I am struggling

```
function add_cart(pid,quantity) {
$.ajax({        
    type    : 'POST',
    url     : '../../ajax/add-cart.php',
    data    : 'pid='+pid+'&quantity='+quantity,
    success : function() {}
});
}
```

The problem is that some pages that call this ajax request have 2 directories others have up to 4 directories, when it has more than 2 directories it returns a 404. I tried changing the path to the absolute url, http://www.mydomain.com/ajax/add-cart.php, but that didn't work either. 
Is there some easy was to correct this, without having to go through a big hack?

Comment: In asp.net I typically resolve the absolute url using a server side construct, and assign it to a JS variable that I reference in the JS script

Answer (score 0):

a absolute link should work. if it doesn't you probably got a cross-site-request issue (maybe the page is https and the link is http?)

change the url to 
`/ajax/add-cart.php` or `document.location.origin+"/ajax/add-cart.php"`  or `"//www.mydomain.com/ajax/add-cart.php"`

if none else works you can always open the network tab (firebug or chrome-dev console) and check what the url ended up being ( and compare it to your first method that worked) also check what status code the server returned

Comment: both 404d. Ok, will go through Firebug see what I can find

Answer (score 0):

Pass the absolute path without the domain, e.g. `/ajax/add-cart.php`